# Session value isn't show in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to show username into top right side of my header in my laravel webpage but the value isn't shown.

After login successfully I have set the `username` into `Session` but the value doesn't show. No error shown also!

*Controller*

```
Session::put('user_id', $data->id);
Session::put('user_name', $data->name);
Session::put('user_email', $data->email);

return redirect('/home');
```

*In blade*

`{{ Session::get('name') }}`

How to solve that? Where is the problem? Anybody help please?

Comment: If one of the below posts answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same name..
In controller you assigned value to another variable..

```
Session::put('user_id', $data->id);
Session::put('user_name', $data->name);
Session::put('user_email', $data->email);
```

So use that variables in your view.

```
 {{Session::get('user_id')}}
 {{Session::get('user_name')}}
 {{Session::get('user_email')}}
```

Comment: ....tit's working...will u please tell me that how to check that the value exist or not ? if i logout then how to check  it ?

Comment: You can check whether this session variable is set or not using @if(Session::get('user_name'))

Answer (score 1):

Going off the code in your question, you're looking for `name` but you haven't stored a value with `name`. I'm assuming it should be `user_name`. Try changing your code to be:

```
{{ Session::get('user_name') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the name `user_name` instead of `name` in your view

```
  {{ Session::get('user_name') }}
```